# jQuery slider will not display at max

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery slider.  Its range is 0 to 200

When it displays, the slider is at the far left on 0.

I want it to display on the far right, at 200.

I have tried using:

```
$('#slider').val(200)
```

and the most that happens is the minimum range (value displayed on far left) changes to 200.

Has anyone made jQuery slider behave like I describe?

Versions:

jQuery 1.11.1

jQuery-mobile 1.4.5

jQuery-ui 1.11.2

Here's the html:

```
<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="0.0" min="0.5" max="200" />
```

Here's the javascript (I use console.log to dump val, it is 200":

```
$("#slider-1").slider( "value", val );
```

and here is the error:

```
"Uncaught Error: no such method 'value' for slider widget instance",
```

Comment: Which jQuery library you use?

Comment: added library versions to the post.  sorry about that

Comment: Did you try `"value"` instead of `.val` ?  http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value

Comment: You are doing it wrong.
Please check this docs http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value

Comment: i've tried value as suggested and posted the results above

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of a slider, use `.slider("value", value)`, eg:

```
$("#slider").slider("value", 200);
```

More info: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value

Answer (score 0):

The correct use of method `value` is :

```
$("#slider").slider("value", 200);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/a6e8dtw9/

**EDIT**

If you want to use html5 `input type="range"` you ll find an exemple here :

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/x4tet97w/

Comment: your slider is a <div>.  mine is an <input > tag.  do you think that has anything to do with the weird error i'm getting?

Comment: According to the documentation you should use a div as a container of the the slider. https://jqueryui.com/slider/